# Syntax Errors when trying to insert into database

Tags: .net

iwant to insert into a database, but i get this error that says " syntax error near the keyword 'table'. please note that the keyword table is the name of the table where i want to onsert the data..
whats wrong with my code
can anyone help...

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] imageData = ReadFile(textBox8.Text);
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into Table values(@NationalID,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@DateOfBirth,@Gender,@Address,@HomeTown,@StateOfOrigin,@MaritalStatus,@JobStatus,@ImagePath,@Image)", cn);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("NationalID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("MiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox4.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("HomeTown", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox6.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("StateOfOrigin", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("MaritalStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("JobStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ImagePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox8.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", (object)imageData));
            //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pictureBox1.Image;
            cn.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
```

Comment: This is why **you never name tables `table`**. You need to quote/escape it.

Answer (score 1):

"Table" is a sql server reserved word. If it is actually the name of your table, then you need to surround the name with square brackets: [Table]

Comment: Thank you, done that but it raises another exception that says " string or binary data will be truncated"

Comment: that is a different problem - it means that you are trying to insert too much data into a column - for example, putting a 100 character string into a varchar(50) column